# Wait for data from flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

Is there any way how can I wait for data from `Flow` and then for example log it? I have problem that code will run asynchrounously, `Log.d` is fired before data are available...

This is my code:

```
    repository.getData().onEach {
        state = state.copy(data = it)
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)

    Log.d("test", "loadData: ${state.data}")
```

Comment: You can log it inside the `onEach` you already have there, or if you are changing `state` from multiple places and want to log all of them, then `state.onEach { log }.launchIn(viewModelScope)`

Comment: I need to work with state :)

Comment: ok, can you explain what you want to do with state? And state is some kind of flow or just plain variable?

Comment: It is UI state... I need to get data from flow and then work with it within same function in ViewModel

Comment: Then you probably have to launch a coroutine, in it you can do `state = repo.getData().first()`. "waiting" in non-suspending context is not doable unless you do non-recommended hack of using `runBlocking`.

Comment: .first() is exactly what I looked for :) I throught it will also return Flow.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use coroutineBuilder :

```
runBlocking -> if you want to block the current thread 

launch or aysnc ->if you don't want to block the current thread
```

and then you should call`join` method on the coroutinebuilder

example->

```
val job = launch{
    repository.getData().onEach {
        state = state.copy(data = it)
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
job.join()
Log.d("test", "loadData: ${state.data}")
```